# Black-Scholes model from probability tree, Hull 13a.6

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, finance

The following is an excerpt from Hull's book "[Options, Futures and Other Derivatives (9th edition)](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Hull-Options-Futures-and-Other-Derivatives-9th-Edition/PGM286628.html)",  page 299:

> $$p^{*}=\left(\frac{e^{r T / n}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}{e^{\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}\right)\left(\frac{e^{\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}{e^{r T / n}}\right)\tag{13a.6}
> $$
>
> By expanding the exponential functions in a series we see that, as $n$ tends to infinity, $p^{*}\left(1-p^{*}\right)$ tends to $1 / 4$ and $\sqrt{n}\left(p^{*}-1 / 2\right)$ tends to
> $$
> \frac{\left(r+\sigma^{2} / 2\right) \sqrt{T}}{2 \sigma}\tag{13a.7}
> $$

Could someone explain why $p^*$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ (or rather, why $p^*\times(1-p^*)$ tends to $\frac14$), and why $\sqrt{n}\left(p^{*}-1 / 2\right)$ tends to the equation noted as $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Without looking at the detail, presumably as $n$ increases, the probability of a small uptick gets closer to $1/2$, but with a small upward bias proportional to $1/\sqrt{n}$.  So  $p^* (1-p^*)\to 1/4$ and $\sqrt{n}(p^*-1/2) \to$ as stated and derived from the exponential terms

Comment: @henry thanks! is there some...  book or notes i can read so i understand how the lim n infinity stuff works? from my understanding hes using taylor series, and disregarding n^2+ terms, but even so i don't see how he reaches his conclusions

Comment: Please note that [images of text and mathematical expressions are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Mathematical expressions should be formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on MSE.

Comment: @KReiser i'm not really sure what that math jax is, i simplified the equation somewhat, can this question be unlocked?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and the links there.

Comment: If the $a$ is supposed to be a $\sigma$, you can format the latter with `\sigma`.

Comment: relevant https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54913/black-scholes-formula-derivation-from-a-binomial-tree-john-c-hull?newreg=8880d1e798c14cbba6d85c3d5716cc12

Comment: Edited after off site convo with OP

Comment: There is some missing setup to the problem (which was also missing before the edits that dramatically improved the post), such as assuming $T \gt 0$.  In fact an attempt to work this out will likely reduce the number of variables involved to one or two.  As a first step to show you tried to solve it, check what happens when you let $x = \sqrt{T/k}$.  Note that $k\to \infty$ implies $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: [Shameless plug](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123) link where I explain taylor

Comment: @hardmath hey i am not at all familiar with lim approach 0 or infinity stuff. I'm reading this book which is normally pretty straightforward, but in this one section goes crazy. can you please just show me how to solve it, instead of everyone looking om saying "it's so easy".

Comment: @hardmath it's really disappointing for me. i can send u photos of pages of maths i did before, I'm not sure what you're looking for or why you need to see this before helping another human being.

Comment: @hardmath at the moment I'm helping train african engineers to get jobs in the us, i do this for free. when I train them i ask them if they know how to do something. if they don't i simply show them.  people have different styles of learning, some visual, some theoretical, some from memory etc. i invite you to consider this when you respond to future questions from other people. not everyone needs to have the research etc skills to be a professor (say) in maths. some people merely need the solution to move on.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai this is a good tutorial, thankyou.

Comment: Sure that's reasonable given your background is not "familiar with lim approach 0 or infinity stuff," but your Question didn't reflect that limited background.  Indeed one would think that having understood all that went before in the book (it makes references back to earlier pages), you know about limits at least to the extend of first year calculus.  Is that how I should shape my response?  Or do you have less familiarity, e.g a pre-college math background?

Comment: @hardmath i just would like to know the limit work. i did maths at uni -  more than a decade ago -  so i can do basic differentials, some pdes etc. but it's incredibly rusty for me.

Comment: when i did the limit work, i ended up with $(e^0 -  e^0)/(e^0 -  e^0) times (e^0/e^0 )$ which is very much not $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It is essential to add that into the body of your Question.  Readers such as myself can then appreciate that you have a naive understanding of limits and work with you where you are to arrive at a sensible result.

Comment: [Check out this article](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-introduction-to-limits/) to see how the concept of limits work so you get a better view on what's going on here

Comment: I think there was a bit of miscommunication w/ in your exchange with hardmath. The condition he mentioned is critical in finding their correct answer, if the condition is not satisfied a different answer maybe arrived at. As extra information you need to give the definition of σ,T,r or at least what signs are @bharal

Comment: The [Black-Scholes model](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blackscholes.asp) gives an equation to price a European-style call option (one that may be exercised only at expiration and not before).  It is important to clarify which variables are simple real values and which are random values.

Comment: Did you abandon the question? :(

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai sort of. the quant se ppl pointed me in the right direction with using $1 + x + x^2$, and i just fudged it so i got the 1/2 and the other answer. actually all this maths seems pretty fudgy but i guess that's fine? its just like big o notation...

Comment: mmmm i can pop the calcs here later. but really, thankyou for helping me use the dolla notation, and your post on taylor series is REALLY GOOD

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai u should put that stuff on substack, medium always hassles me to pay for things but if you wrote maths posts I'd pay you for it.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment haha. I'll think about it haha. And I mean yeah, you're dealing with the asymptotic behavior afterall, so it is sort of fudgy stuff. Do let me know once you edit in the attempt, it'll be good practice with latex. I'll go through it @bharal

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai my phone died midway. sigh.

Comment: You're supposed to be writing math jax on computer not phone... @bharal

Answer (score 0):

$e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/3!...$

This is from the most excellent blog post here - [Taylor series](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

(Admittedly I do not understand the difference between Taylor and maclauren from it, but that seems unimportant).

Now in our problem, we have:

$p^{*}=\left(\frac{e^{r T / n}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}{e^{\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}\right)\left(\frac{e^{\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}{e^{r T / n}}\right)\tag{13a.6}$

$\frac{e^{r T / n}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}}{e^{\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}-e^{-\sigma \sqrt{T / n}}} $

Which can boil down to

So we have:

Comment: Maclaurin is when you take the information of derivatives about x=0 for writiing the series, Taylro is when you do it about a general point x=a

Comment: You posted this as a self-answer, which suggests you have as much of an understanding of the passage quoted from Hull as you wanted.  However if your seemingly incomplete edit to the end of this self-answer is an indication, you may still be working at the simplification of the two limits, $p^*$ and $\sqrt n (p^* - 1/2)$.  In that case I renew my suggestion to try the substitution $x = \sqrt{T/n}$ to reduce the amount of algebra required.